# Externally trigger an Azure DevOps Build using a Sevice Principal account

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to have a service principal account trigger a build pipeline? I have a CMS that whenever a document is published it fires of an event/webhook that's calls an Azure Function. The function then calls Azure DevOps using the API to trigger the correct build pipeline. Up until now we have relied on personal access tokens (PAT) from a "lucky" team member, but obviously that isn't an ideal solution. If the PAT expires or the team member leaves our pipeline breaks down. I was hoping to use the PAT Lifecycle Management API* to generate a PAT on the fly, but as the documentation states; *"On-behalf-of application" solutions (such as the “client credential” flow) and any authentication flow that does not issue an Azure AD access token is not valid for use with this API"*.

This seems like a fairly common scenario, having an external dependency kicking of a build pipeline, so how should I go about doing this without using person-dependent tokens?

- https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/manage-personal-access-tokens-via-api?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Externally trigger an Azure DevOps Build using a Sevice Principal account

I am afraid it it impossible to use REST API to trigger an Azure DevOps Build using a Sevice Principal account.

That because the **Azure DevOps API doesn't support non-interactive service access via service principals**.

You could get the info from the document [Choose the right authentication mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops)：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It should now be possible to authentication using a Service Principal or Managed Identity. This feature was [first announced as a preview](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/introducing-service-principal-and-managed-identity-support-on-azure-devops/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655) in March 2023.

See documentation [Authenticate with service principals & managed identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/service-principal-managed-identity?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001655)